# Show that for a vector $d$, $(I_n + dd^T)^{-1} = I_n - \frac{1}{1+||d||^2}dd^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to show that for a vector $d$, $(I_n + dd^T)^{-1} = I_n - \frac{1}{1+||d||^2}dd^T$.

Looking at the expression I immediately recall the equality for a general matrix
$$(C+DD^T) = C^{-1}D(I+D^TC^{-1}D)^{-1}D^{-1}$$
However, it requires $D$ to be invertible whereas in this case, $d$ is a vector.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: just do the multiplication and see that you get the identity

Comment: This is just a special case of the Sherman-Morrison formula, see here for the result and proof: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula

Comment: Use $||d||^2=d^Td$. Note that it's a scalar.

Comment: Your formula is incorrect. It should be
$$
(C + DD^T) = C^{-1} - C^{-1}D(I + D^TC^{-1}D)^{-1}D^TC^{-1},
$$
which is an instance of the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity). There is no requirement that $D$ be invertible.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, it can be done by directly showing $$(I_n+dd^T)(I_n-\frac{1}{1+\|d\|^2}dd^T)=I_n$$

just using the fact that $d^Td=\|d\|^2$. Here is another approach.

On the orthogonal complement of $d$, we have both of $I_n+dd^T$ and $I_n-\frac{1}{1+\|d\|^2}dd^T$ are just the identity operator, hence must be inverses of each other. It now remains to show they are inverses of each other for $d$ (hence the subspace generated by $d$) as well.

Indeed, $(I_n+dd^T)d=d+d(d^Td)=(1+\|d\|^2)d$ is just the multiplication by $1+\|d\|^2$ operator. While $(I_n-\frac{1}{1+\|d\|^2}dd^T)d=\frac{1}{1+\|d\|^2}d$ is just the multiplication by $\frac{1}{1+\|d\|^2}$ operator, hence they must be inverses of each other on the subspace generated by $d$ as well.

The same method can be used to show the Sherman-Morrison formula (though $\mathbb Rd$ and its orthogonal complement are not necessarily invariant subspaces).